# Package not found for awk.exe and csh.exe in Cygwin 2.10.0

Tags: cygwin, awk, tcsh, csh

I'm upgrading from cygwin 1.7.35 to cygwin 2.10.0. But I could not find any package that contains awk & csh binaries (.exe). When I type `info csh` or `info awk` in cygwin(2.10.0) terminal it shows the output for `gawk` and `tcsh` command. Will this newer version affect the scripts that make use of these commands(`awk` & `csh`)?

Comment: yes @Biswapriyo

Comment: Try to uninstall and reinstall them with their full dependencies.

Comment: I already did. I think in the newer version of cygwin awk is linked to gawk and csh is linked to tcsh. @Biswapriyo

Comment: Yes you are right. This problem happens once in my pc when I set cygwin folder permission to all user recursively. Reinstalling the `awk` solves my issue. So the I'm out of idea.

Answer (score 1):

awk was always performed by gawk in cygwin.

```
$ ls -l /usr/bin/awk*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 .... /usr/bin/awk -> gawk.exe
```

It never changed, it was already there in the oldest announcement I found in the archive on the matter. https://sourceware.org/ml/cygwin-announce/2000/msg00033.html

As the manual says:

```
NAME
       gawk - pattern scanning and processing language

...    
DESCRIPTION
       Gawk  is  the  GNU Project's implementation of the AWK programming language
```

Same for tcsh: An enhanced version of csh, the C shell

$ ls -l /usr/bin/csh*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 ..... /usr/bin/csh -> tcsh.exe